# How to get an absolute value of Around?

Tags: intervals, error-propagation, around

`Around` is a useful feature of Mathematica 12 to work with uncertain data.

```
x = Around[-1, {0.5, 1.5}]
```

> $-1.0^{+1.5}_{-0.5}$

I'm curious how to get an absolute value of such uncertain data.
When I use `Abs` directly I get an unexpected result:

```
Abs[x]
```

> $1.0^{+1.5}_{-0.5}$

I have expected:
 $1.0^{+0.5}_{-1.0}$, because

```
Abs[x["Interval"]]
```

> Interval[{0, 1.5}]

In total there are two issues:

1. Upper and lower uncertainties are not interchanged when taking `Abs`.
2. Crossing of zero is ignored.

Is this intended behaviour of `Around` or some sort of a bug?

How should I calculate absolute values of uncertain data points? For example, when I want to plot `Abs` of uncertain of data?

**Update**

Simple multiplication by a negative number gives incorrect result:

```
(-1)*x
```

> $1.0^{+1.5}_{-0.5}$ (* Correct answer is $1.0^{+0.5}_{-1.5}$*)

Comment: That some for support. `Around` is pretty new and apparently very buggy. Or the two uf us haven't understood the deeper meaning of `Around`, yet.

Comment: I guess @HenrikSchumacher's comment should begin *That's one for support.* ?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "buggy", it just looks like `Abs` doesn't support `Around` in its initial implementation (unless it is documented to do so). But if you'd like it to, then yes, reach out to support and ask for it.

Comment: @user6014 There are better ways to implement unimplemented functions, for example, keep the original symbolic form. Since it evaluates to incorrect result without warnings I would call it a bug. BTW multiplication of `Around` by a number is documented but still produces incorrect result.

Comment: `-Around[-1, {0.5, 1.5}]` has similar problems. The behavior of `About` seems consistent with `f[About[x, {a,b}]]` being `About[f[x], {Abs[f'[x]]*a, Abs[f'[x]]*b}]`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would be acceptable as an answer, for the sake of expediency (assuming you just want a quick answer!), here is what you could write to keep this working for you:

```
abs[val_, lBound_, uBound_] := 
  Around[Abs[val], 
   If[val > 0, {lBound, uBound}, Reverse@{lBound, uBound}]];
abs[-1, 0.5, 1.5]
```

I hope this helps.